# Using a static method with a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, static, popup, jframe

I have this method which is going to run at the start of my program:

```
public static void checkIntegrity(){
        File propertiesFile = new File("config.properties");
        if (propertiesFile.exists()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "File was found");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "File was not found");
        }
    }
```

It essentially checks if the `config.properties` file is missing or not and displays a popup accordingly.

This is my `main` function:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {  
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
                checkIntegrity();
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem with this is that the `checkIntegrity()` function uses `rootPane` to display the popup in order to inform the user. `rootPane` though is a non-static member so it is not possible to use it in `checkIntegrity()`.

Is there a way to make `checkIntegrity()` show the popup while still being a static function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A couple of different ways. First of all, you could use `null` instead of `rootPane`:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File was found");
```

You could also pass the function rootPane:

```
GUI pane = new GUI().setVisible(true);
checkIntegrity(pane);
```

and change the function deceleration accordingly:

```
public static void checkIntegrity(GUI rootPane){
```

You could finally make `rootPane` a static variable (this is the way I would do it):

```
class theClass{
    static GUI rootPane;
    public static void main...
```

For this last one, you also have to set `rootPane`:

```
rootPane = new GUI().setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I am looking for a way that is going to change my code as less as possible and I think I will do it with the `null` way but could you explain to me why you would prefer your final way? All I can see as a difference from using `null` vs `rootPane` is that the position of the popup is not in the center of the `rootPane`. Is there any other reason I should not use `null`?

Comment: @SilliconTouch Nice question. Both will work. However, I prefer not passing it `null` because the behavior of a dialog is to block clicking on the main window. When you pass it `null`, this will not happen (if you don't like the behavior, use `null`). As for which way to pass it `rootPane`, I prefer the last because in my opinion it is the most OO way.

Comment: I think I will pass the `rootPane` then with your last method. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)` method allows you to pass null as the first parameter, so you don't need to be concerned about whether or not `rootPane` is static.  Another option is that you can make the method `checkIntegrity()` non-static.  This would mean that in your `main()` method you will need to create an instance of `rootPane` first, then call the `checkIntegrity()` method, like so:

```
RootPane rootPane = new RootPane();
rootPane.checkIntegrity();
```